# How to fix 'Waiting for build to finish' error on Android Studio 3.5

Tags: android, android-studio

While I was working on a view on my project, Android Studio suddenly started to show me 'Waiting for build to finish' message when I try to edit some layouts.

I have researched on the Internet and none of the solutions worked.

Things I've tried:

- Removed .gradle folder from root of my project and from my home
  folder (MacOS)
- Uninstalled and reinstalled Android Studio with all it's leftover files. It was a complete removing.
- Tried to tweak androidx library versions.
- Clean / Rebuild Project
- Invalidate cache and restart
- Try on an empty project
- Try on an existing but different project than I'm having trouble with.
- Updated to latest version Android Studio 3.5
- Updated to latest gradle and gradle plugin

In short, nothing on the internet or on the stackoverflow helped me.

Edit: I have solved the problem by myself.

Comment: If you click on the message "Waiting to Build" do you see a pop up window with the ability click a Play Button?

Comment: No I don't. There's no Play Button appears when I click on 'Waiting to Build'. But I can run my application and deploy it on a real device successfully.

Comment: im also facing this problem and i have no idea what happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution is found by myself.

If Android Studio keeps telling you waiting for build to finish, it's **actually** waiting for build to finish.

Sometimes people get confused when the status bar of AS says 'Gradle Build finished' but actually it's important to check the actual build is completed or not.

In Build screen there's a tab called 'Build Output' and I noticed that my app poped up some errors related to androidx and android support libraries. So I went back to non androidx version of my project and everything seems to working just fine.

There was a dependency for camera view using androidx and so I migrated my whole project to AndroidX because I was depreate enough to use that library no matter what happens. It ended up taking my whole day for fixing it.

Comment: Build output says BUILD SUCCESSFULL, but still preview shows "Waiting for build to finish". I also had issues with camerax, so ended not using it at all. <rant>Lately android development seems to be less and less stable...</rant>

Comment: It's indeed. It was trying to use [this library](https://github.com/natario1/CameraView) and its latest version is compiled with androidx. (I hope the original author of the library won't get mad at me) I downloaded the library and made some changes on the library code itself. I changed androidx imports to old support imports and my problem was solved! Now I can use that awesome library and my design window works just fine! You can try the same approach with camerax if you haven't done it already with something else.

Comment: there are a lot of tasks involved when building the final assembly, especially when jetifier is enabled, so maybe there is a deadlock somewhere in the way.